# How to groupby with multiple keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, group-by

Thank you in advance to whoever can help me. I am trying to show data in expandable rows in tabular format. How can i groupby with multiple keys like height,type and rank.

I know stackoverflow is not for asking for code but being noob and beginner, stackoverflow is the only option i have. Please show your talent to help me out.

> I need this for First semester 1 credit college project.

i have a object

```
 const sensorData = [{
  "id": 19,
  "height": 3.0,
  "orientation": null,
  "rank": "Primary",
  "relativeHeight": 4,
  "stat": "min",
  "type": "wdir",
},
{
  "id": 19,
  "height": 3.0,
  "orientation": null,
  "rank": "Primary",
  "relativeHeight": 6,
  "stat": "min",
  "type": "wdir",
},
{
  "id": 19,
  "height": 1.0,
  "orientation": null,
  "rank": "Primary",
  "relativeHeight": 6,
  "stat": "min",
  "type": "wdir",
}]
```

The output i want is:

```
[  
   {  
      "isExpandable":true,
      "common":{  
         "height":3.0,
         "rank":"Primary",
         "type":"wdir"
      },
      "data":[  
         {  
            "id":19,
            "orientation":null,
            "relativeHeight":4,
            "stat":"max"
         },
         {  
            "id":19,
            "orientation":null,
            "relativeHeight":6,
            "stat":"min"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "isExpandable":false,
      "id":19,
      "height":1.0,
      "orientation":null,
      "rank":"Primary",
      "relativeHeight":6,
      "stat":"min",
      "type":"wdir"
   }
]
```

I found reduce and lodash (_groupBy) very difficult to achieve this.

> Updated: 
>       isExpandable is decided if any attribute are matched or object can be grouped.

Thanks

Comment: You should add proper explanation about how `isExpandable` is decided ?

Comment: question is updated, ask any thing you need .
Please thanks

Comment: `id` is same in all of the obejcts but you still have two of them in a group one in another group, be clear and specific about your question !!!

Comment: yes here we are only categorizing with height,type and rank. other's value can be ignored